# Segmentation fault in av_register_all

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I am just initializing ffmpeg by calling av_register_all in Android jni code

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testplayer_MainActivity_ffmpegOpen( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring path)
{

    const char *input_filename =  "mtbiketribe-small.mp4";
    av_register_all();
    return env->NewStringUTF("Success in av_register_all");

}
```

I am including libavcodec, libavformat, libavutil in extern "C" in the file.
In makefile I am including prebuilt ffmpeg.so.

My code is building fine but on running the code I am getting error in av_register_all.

```
segmentation fault :fatal signal 11 at 0xa660001d.
```

Please point why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is unlikely anyone would be able to help you with the limited information you provided. Most likely the `FFmpeg` build you're using is not compatible with your device/CPU. Are you running it on an emulator?

If you want to debug it, what you need to do is to compile a standalone C application which would only have an  `av_register_all` call, and run it under `gdb` so you can trace the crash.